# Angular 8 ngFor not biding

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have the League of Legends Champion API witch returns what I'm getting from the champions.service.

**.ts** Updated

```js
    
    @Component({   selector: 'app-champions',   templateUrl: './champions.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./champions.component.css'] })
    
    export class ChampionsComponent implements OnInit {
    
      public champions;   
      public arrayChampions;  
      
         constructor(private championsService:ChampionsService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getAllChampions();   }
    
     getAllChampions(){
    this.championsService.getChampions().subscribe(
      data => { this.champions = data, 
        this.arrayChampions = Object.entries(this.champions.data).map(([k,v]) => ({ [k]:v })),
        this.ArrayIterator(); 
      },
      err => {console.error(err)},
      () => console.log("Champions cargados")
    );
  }

  ArrayIterator() {
    let IteratableArray = Array();
    for (let item of Object.keys(this.arrayChampions[0])) {
      var eventItem = Object.values(this.arrayChampions[0]);
      IteratableArray.push(eventItem);
    }
    this.arrayChampions = IteratableArray[0];
  }
    
    
    }
```

**champions.service**

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
 
    const httpOptions = {   
     headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) 
    }
 
    @Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) export class ChampionsService {
 
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 
    getChampions(){
     return this.http.get('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.23.1/data/es_ES/champion.json');
    }
```

**HTML:**

```html
    <div *ngFor="let arrayChampion of arrayChampions>
        <a class="text-decoration-none">{{arrayChampion.id}}</a>
    </div>
```

The fact is that nothing appears in the HTML. I don't know really well which is the problem.

Comment: you missed the closing `"` at the end of your `*ngFor` loop

Comment: Also on initial load `arrayChampions.id` is null so nothing will display, you may need to refresh your dom once you have run `getAllChampions`, are you getting any console errors when you initially load the page ?

Comment: Can you also post your code from `championsService` so we can see how you are retrieving the data?

Comment: champion service added. I already corrected the " at the en of *ngFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array first element is an `object` since because of that you cannot iterate it straightly in the template. Therefore you need to transform it accordingly to be able to iterate over through the template. For that you can proceed with the following :

> From here with I am attaching the working stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-hznicw?file=app/app.component.ts)

**Sample HTML :**

```
<div *ngFor="let arrayChampion of arrayChampions>
    <a class="text-decoration-none">{{arrayChampion.id}}</a>
</div>
```

**Sample component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular 4";
  arrayChampions: any;
  data = [
    {
      Aatrox: {
        id: "Aatrox",
        key: "266"
      },
      Ahri: {
        id: "Ahri",
        key: "103"
      },
      Akali: {
        id: "Akali",
        key: "84"
      }
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ArrayIterator();
  }

  ArrayIterator() {
    let IteratableArray = Array();
    for (let item of Object.keys(this.data[0])) {
      var eventItem = Object.values(this.data[0]);
      IteratableArray.push(eventItem);
    }
    this.arrayChampions = IteratableArray[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help.
I have already copy what you did in the stackblitz example, but now I'm getting the first champion only. And I Added the champions.service

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013467/why-array-only-brings-one-object-in-angular-project can u help me please?

Comment: I have updated answer there. Please mark it as coorect and give an up vote too. If there is anything needs clarify pring me up with comment. @Robert