# Why array only brings one object in Angular project?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I'm working with the League of Legends API, more specific with the champion json they bring.

I have this service made with Angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChampionsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getChampions(){
    return this.http.get('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.23.1/data/es_ES/champion.json');
  }

}
```

This is my .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ChampionsService } from '../../services/champions.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-champions',
  templateUrl: './champions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./champions.component.css']
})

export class ChampionsComponent implements OnInit {

  public champions;
  public arrayChampions;
  
  
  constructor(private championsService:ChampionsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllChampions();
  }

  getAllChampions(){
    this.championsService.getChampions().subscribe(
      data => { this.champions = data, 
        this.arrayChampions = Object.entries(this.champions.data).map(([k,v]) => ({ [k]:v })),
        this.ArrayIterator(); 
      },
      err => {console.error(err)},
      () => console.log("Champions cargados")
    );
  }

  ArrayIterator() {
    let IteratableArray = Array();
    for (let item of Object.keys(this.arrayChampions[0])) {
      var eventItem = Object.values(this.arrayChampions[0]);
      IteratableArray.push(eventItem);
    }
    this.arrayChampions = IteratableArray[0];
  }
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<p>champions works!</p>
{{arrayChampions | json}}
 <!-- Cards -->
<div *ngFor="let arrayChampion of arrayChampions" class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <a class="text-decoration-none">{{arrayChampion.id}}</a>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the var "arrayChampions" only brings the first champion (Atrox) when it should bring all the champions as I understand (I'm new at javascript and Angular).

Comment: I think there was a problem with your ArrayIterator, I made a simple test in stackblizt here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-http-client-qqg9ay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html , and its work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your exmaple I have created and stackblitz here, And it made the whole `arrayChampions` Iterate over its values.

> Please find the working stacblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-http-client-zfpni4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Sample HTML :**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<!-- {{this.products |json}} -->
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let champ of products | keyvalue">
        <label style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;color: red;">
      {{champ.key}}
    </label>
        <ul *ngFor="let item of champ.value | keyvalue">
            <li>
                {{item.key}} : {{item.value}}
                <ul *ngFor="let sub of item.value | keyvalue">
                    <li>
                        {{sub.key}} : {{sub.value}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Sample component.ts :**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map, catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  apiURL: string =
    "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.23.1/data/es_ES/champion.json";
  name = "Angular";
  products = [];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getChamp();
  }

  getChamp() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.apiURL).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.products = data.data;
      Object.keys(data.data).map((key: any, obj: any) => obj[key]);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I applied your code and it works. Can you tell me the teoric explanation to understand please?

Comment: Sure.. What happens in this line `Object.keys(data.data).map((key: any, obj: any) => obj[key]);` does the magic. It gets your heros response from the API call and iterates over each object and gets each objects value by its key and assign it in another array which your template can iterate over. Thats what happens in that line. I highly appreciate an upvote in both the answers if possible. Happy to help